# is unit test approach a bad one?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm testing a class, which has pretty much dependencies from other classes. To solve this I use mocks. That worked very well so far.

```
[Test]
public void DataField_Gets_Properly_Created()
{
    // Arrange all those mocks

    _dataField =  new DataField(dependency1, dependency2, dependency3);

    Assert.NotNull(dataField.Id);
    // other assertions ...
}

[Test]
public void DataField_Gets_Properly_Saved()
{
    var entityList = new List<IEntity>();
    var dfId = Guid.NewGuid();

    _dataField.SetValue(true, entityList, dfId);

    Assert.True(_datenFeld.ValueBoolean);
    // other assertions
}
```

As you can see I use this private `_dataField` variable. You know, I actually test if a data field can be created in the first test. Is it a bad approach to use the same data field in the second test, which just got created in the first method? I think this isn't very clean code.

The second idea I've had was creating this data field in the `[Setup]`. This isn't very clean either, because how should I create it in the setup and test afterwards if it even can be created? I'm confused.

Afterwards could be even more tests which all need an instance of a data field to test the actual class `DataField`.

Comment: Your tests should be independent of each other. The execution of one test should not affect the execution of any other test.

Comment: So the only way would be a setup, right? But with the first test I'd test if the creation in the setup worked fine. The first test just tests if a data field, which gets instantiated, has the expected "must have" fields set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unit test should not depend on any other unit tests.  You should be able to run each one individually and have them pass, and you should be able to run them in any arbitrary order.

In this case, I'd recommend using a local variable that you re-initialize in each test, but arrange all the mocks in the `[Setup]`.  You can encapsulate the initialization in a helper method, `CreateDataFieldForTest()` or similar.

Comment: This re-initializing sounds good to me. I also think that nesting the mock creation in the `[TestFixtureSetup]`'d be better, wouldn't it?

Comment: `[Setup]` is more isolated, but it also depends on your situation.

Comment: What do you mean with "more isolated"?

Comment: In `[Setup]`, the object gets recreated every time, so you wouldn't have any danger of stale object state leaking into a subsequent test.

Answer (score 3):

Your unit tests should not be dependent on other unit tests.

The function marked with `[Setup]` will be called before **every** `[Test]` function in your class.  So if you move the `_dataField` creation to `[Setup]`, it will continually recreate it.  Is that what you are unsure of?

A function marked with `[TestFixtureSetUp]` will be called once at the start of a `[TestFixure]`.  So it wont be called before every `[Test]`

```
[SetUp]
public void TestSetup()
{
   _dataField =  new DataField(dependency1, dependency2, dependency3);
}

[Test]
public void DataField_Gets_Properly_Created()
{
    Assert.NotNull(dataField.Id);
    // other assertions ...
}

[Test]
public void Most_Test_Using_dataField()
{
    ...
}
```

Here the first test will fail if its not 'initialized' properly.  In this case, you'll know there is a problem and cant guarantee other Tests will work.

Comment: I know that this happens. The first test just tests if the `new DataField(d1, d2, ...)` initialized the data field properly. So I'd have to test if the data field which got created in the `[Setup]` got initialized properly. That's something which sounds pretty unclean to me.

Comment: @ebeeb - I dont think its unclean.  If you have just the initialization there, it will be fine.  Then have your first test make sure that object is valid.  I updated with example.

Comment: In other words: the first test tests if the `[TextFixtureSetup]` works properly? I just think that this setup *must* be fine and doesn't need any more verification. Or am I wrong with this?